# Why can´t I read or edit recently created records using Salesforce1 offline?

Tags: salesforce1-app, offline, cache

I´m creating a new record (when login to salesforce via browser or salesforce1 online), the system creates 5 records in other 5 objects, each with a master detail relation with, every time the "parent" record es created.

When I go to Salesforce1, and refresh cache, via salesforce1 settings (Settings ->  Offline Cache -> Cache Now) I am able to see the record I created listed on the object list view, however I´m not able to see record details, I get this error:

> Check your network connection and try again.

In addition, expected behavior is that user is able to read and edit the recently created record and the **Child** records.

Which records will be available when I click Cache Now? 
Recently created records count as recent records?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_sf1_offline_view.htm&type=0&language=en_US):

> The Cache Now option collects recently accessed records for the first five objects listed in the Recent section of the user’s Salesforce1 navigation menu, plus the user’s recent tasks and dashboards. Recently accessed records are determined by a user's activities in both Salesforce1 and the full Salesforce site, including Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience.

This means that you should have access to the created object, but not necessarily the childs (since they are not accessed). And of course, you'll only be able to fetch data when you're online and cache it to use later.